OpenId Connect + .NET 8 Isolated - How to implement OIDC in an Azure Function?
I'm studying ways to integrate OpenId Connect with Azure Function + .NET 8 Isolated Mode and, as I haven't found better links on the internet, I would like to know the best way to do this and what steps I could follow.
I would like to know which examples I can follow, which links are useful for more practical research and to know the requirements to meet the demand.

First you need to register the App in Microsoft Entity ID and get the credentials.
Refer this MSDoc to register the App with Identity Provider.


In the registered App, add the platform (Web) and enable the ID Tokens.



The Redirect URI will be your FunctionApp Name if the App is deployed

https://funcad.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback

OR
For Localhost
https://localhost:8000/.auth/login/aad/callback


Create Client Secret and copy the value for reference (to add it in function app).



Create a Function App with .NET 8 Isolated.
In local.settings.json file, add the credentials, you can get the credentials from the Registered App.

My local.settings.json file:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "AzureAd:Instance": "https://login.microsof****tonline.com/",
    "AzureAd:TenantId": "******",
    "AzureAd:ClientId": "******",
    "AzureAd:ClientSecret": "******"
  }
}


Install the Microsoft.Identity.Web package.

Thanks @Try Catch Debug for the clear steps to integrate code in Program.cs and Function file.
Refer this doc and integrate the code.
